# Creating multiplayer TicTacToe

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a tictactoe game where two players can play (as opposed to being vs AI or on the same screen).  To do this, I first created the game to run in one browser window then wanted to expand it to save into a database and then have player 2 open it in a different (incognito) browser and it update when player 1 plays and so on.

First, I created a webpage where player 1 selects his icon (X or O) and inputs his name.  Then this saves this info, with a random key for game id, into a database table and redirects player 1 to the game board.  Here, player 1 can send an email (using PHPmailer) to player 2 with a clickable link to enter their name and then join the game session player 1 is in.

On the actual tictactoe page, I just have 9 blank buttons for the players to click.  There will be an if condition that will take the player turn and only allow the current turn (ie x or o) to actually click and make changes to the buttons, and then save the button clicked into the database and update it onto player 2's screen.

The problem for me is, I can get everything to work on 1 screen, but I have no idea how to save the chosen button into a database, then tell player 2 to load the changes onto his screen.  Meaning I only have it working for 2 players on 1 browser window right now.

Here is an example of my current tictactoe code:

https://jsfiddle.net/yf8x116v/5/

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ttt2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/tttcode.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="player1" align="center">
      <img src="../images/user.png" alt="User1" width="50" height="50">
      <figcaption>Player 1</figcaption>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
        Enter Email to send InviteLink:<input type="text" name="email" />
        <input type="hidden" name="invite" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="board" align="center">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><button class="cell" id="cell_00" type="button" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></button></td>
          <td><button class="cell" id="cell_01" type="button" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></button></td>
          <td><button class="cell" id="cell_02" type="button" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button class="cell" id="cell_10" type="button" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></button></td>
          <td><button class="cell" id="cell_11" type="button" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></button></td>
          <td><button class="cell" id="cell_12" type="button" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button class="cell" id="cell_20" type="button" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></button></td>
          <td><button class="cell" id="cell_21" type="button" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></button></td>
          <td><button class="cell" id="cell_22" type="button" onclick="clickFunction(this)"></button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="player2" align="center">
      <img src="../images/user.png" alt="User2" width="50" height="50">
      <figcaption>Player 2</figcaption>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-sidebar hidden">
    <h3>Players</h3>
    <div id="users"></div>
    <hr/>
    <h3>Spectators</h3>
    <div id="Viewers"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.player1 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%; /*height is done like this so adding padding doesnt make you scroll down */
  float: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding-top: 90px;
}

.board {
    width: 50%;
  height: 100%; /*height is done like this so adding padding doesnt make you scroll down */
  float: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.player2{
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%; /*height is done like this so adding padding doesnt make you scroll down */
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding-top: 90px;
}

table {
    max-width: 320px;
    max-height: 320px;
    width: 85vw;
    height: 85vw;
    border-spacing: 4px 4px;
  }

td {
    padding: 0;
    width: 33%;
    height: 33%;
}

.cell {
    font-size: 3.4em;
    font-size: 12vmin;  /* Responsive font size! Awesome! */
    height: 100%;  /* Fill the container (td) */
    width: 100%;
  background-color:lightgreen;
}

.right-sidebar {
    width: 220px;
    background-color: #d2e6e2;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 50px - 50px);
}

img{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 4px;
  float:center;
}
```

JS

```
var turn = "X";
var moveCount = 0;
var winFlag = 0;

function clickFunction(currentCell) {
  if (currentCell.textContent == ""){
    currentCell.textContent = turn;
    moveCount += 1;
    if(( moveCount < 9) && (winFlag == 0)){
      switchPlayers();
      checkWin();
    }
    else {
      //display draw message
      alert("Draw Game!");
    }
  }
  else{
    //do nothing
  }
}

function switchPlayers(){
  if(winFlag==0){
    if(turn == "X")
      turn = "O";
    else {
      turn = "X";
    }
  }
}

function checkWin(){
  if (
    //check horizontals
    (document.getElementById("cell_00").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_01").textContent && document.getElementById("cell_00").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_02").textContent && (document.getElementById("cell_00").textContent!=""))  ||
    (document.getElementById("cell_10").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_11").textContent && document.getElementById("cell_10").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_12").textContent && (document.getElementById("cell_10").textContent!=""))  ||
    (document.getElementById("cell_20").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_21").textContent && document.getElementById("cell_20").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_22").textContent && (document.getElementById("cell_20").textContent!=""))  ||
    //verticles
    (document.getElementById("cell_00").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_10").textContent && document.getElementById("cell_00").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_20").textContent && (document.getElementById("cell_00").textContent!=""))  ||
    (document.getElementById("cell_01").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_11").textContent && document.getElementById("cell_01").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_21").textContent && (document.getElementById("cell_01").textContent!=""))  ||
    (document.getElementById("cell_02").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_12").textContent && document.getElementById("cell_02").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_22").textContent && (document.getElementById("cell_02").textContent!=""))  ||
    //diagonals
    (document.getElementById("cell_00").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_11").textContent && document.getElementById("cell_00").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_22").textContent && (document.getElementById("cell_11").textContent!=""))  ||
    (document.getElementById("cell_02").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_11").textContent && document.getElementById("cell_02").textContent==document.getElementById("cell_20").textContent && (document.getElementById("cell_11").textContent!=""))){
      //output that someone won and stop the game
      winflag = 1;
      alert("Winner!");
      turn = "";
    }
  else {
    //do nothing and keep playing the game
  }
}
```

(for some reason it doesn't work in jsfiddle but it most definitely works on my computer, sorry)

For a more clear question: where do I go from here to be able to update changes on player 1's screen to player 2's screen so they can see each other playing?

---------EDIT 1-----------------

Okay, taking advice from comments, I want to try AJAX method to check and update database to change the button texts.  For  psuedocode example:

```
onClick(cellID){
   turn = ajax (check whos turn it is in database)
   if ( turn == playerWhoClicked )
      if (cellID.text == "")
         cellID.text = turn
         ajax (update database on which cell was changed to what)
         switchPlayers()
      else
         do nothing
   else  
      do nothing
}

switchPlayers(){
   if (turn == "X")
      turn = "O"
      Ajax (update database turn)
   else
      turn = "X"
      Ajax (update database turn)
}
```

--------------EDIT 2--------------

As per PHPGlue suggested I could also update the database per onClick and use a setInterval to check the database every x seconds to update both player's game boards

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. There are multiple ways to do this which at a high level boil down to polling a server for updates to the data or web sockets. There are tons of ways to implement this.

Comment: I'd recommend investing in one particular approach, because the question as-is won't have any short, straightforward answers.

Comment: still learning php also but off the top i think a good solution will be using notations to indicate which boxes are marked and by which player then no need storing the game play on your data base a simple `.txt file` will do just fine then load the file through php using Ajax

Comment: @BobbyAxe I'm unsure of what any of that means.  However, how would it go about loading to both when one change is made to the... txt file?

Comment: to explain better what i mean by a notation is example box1P1X, box4P2O this means `box 1 marked X by  player 1` and `box 4 marked O by player 2`

Comment: and as for keeping the game in sync for both players look in to simple two way chat app in php using .txt files same principle only that you interpret the notations before display.

Comment: You're going to want to use `setInterval()` for this, because the Client Browser has no idea when the database is updated. Do this only after the game starts and `clearInterval()` when it ends.

Comment: @PHPglue that's something I understand lol. Okay so I would somehow??? make the button press change the database, and have a separate function use setinterval to check changes made and update them into the game? Any ideas on the database part (or if I should use something else)

Comment: Every time a box is checked update a database table, using JavaScript to send data to PHP. I would store a key using [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php), in a database to keep the score between users. Delete the row every so often to same storage. Every so many seconds check to see what the other players boxes are.

Comment: @PHPglue could you put that as an answer, perhaps with a small example?

Comment: @Jacob I edited my post to narrow down what I want.  Any ideas where to find a tutorial that will show me how to do what's in pseudocode? (namely the ajax stuff)

Comment: Do you use node-js or another server system?